# How to display data from API in React Native without error undefined property?

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, api, react-native

I always get undefined property error when I use dataSource[0].first_name in displaying.

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataSource: []
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch('http://api url goes here /api/v1/getUserInfo/40', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'token ' + global.storeToken,
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Error!' + error)
            })

        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: [json],
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { dataSource } = this.state;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Header span style={styles.headerStyle}>
                    <Body style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
                        <Label style={styles.labelNickname}></Label>
                        <Label style={styles.labelUserID}> {dataSource[0].first_name}</Label>
                    </Body>
                </Header>
            </Container>
        );
    };
}
```

The api content is:

```
{
    "id": 40,
    "email": "kk@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Kagura",
    "last_name": "Kinomoto",
    "birth_date": "1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

There's always error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Profile (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:898)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:897)
   etc...
```

What's weird is it worked yesterday after all the console logs and stuff. I only hibernated the laptop, when I tried to run it again today, the error came back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this line to the following.

```
{dataSource && dataSource[0] && dataSource[0].first_name}
```

This will ensure that `dataSource[0]` is not `undefined`.

the reason is that your `fetch` request is asynchronous so `dataSource[0]` is undefined until the response has been received.

Comment: It worked!!! It has been bugging me for weeks and I thought it I had to put them in variables or something. Thank you.